# <hr> no final do texto

Tags: css, html5

Muito boa tarde, estou a desenvolver um website, e o cliente quer algo como está na imagem a baixo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas apenas estou a conseguir colocar assim :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<p>We Offer Clients<br>
    Incorporation Services on a Global Scale<br>
    Free Consultation
</p><hr>
```

Isto é o que tenho, sou novo aqui nao sei se dá para ver o codigo

Alguem me sabe dizer o que me está a falhar?
Cumprimentos

Comment: Sem o código não há como dizer. Poderia elaborar um [mcve]?

Comment: Cara edite a sua pergunta e coloque pelo menos o código que vc já tem até o momento, mesmo que seja apenas uma tag P com a formatação, ou algo mais próximo da sua imagem em código e não só uma foto...

Answer (score 1):

Aqui tem um exemplo

Vc precisa colocar o `P` e o `HR` como elemento em linha, assim um pode se "alinhar" apos o outro e não cair para a linha de baixo. Depois vc precisa colocar uma largura definida no `HR` pois ele perde o escopo quando vc muda o `display` dele, só que dessa forma ele ocupa a tela toda e vc pode precisar colocar esse texto dentro de um *container* com `overflow:hidden` para controlar melhor o efeito...

```css
.box {
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.box p {
    display: inline;
}
.box hr {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <p>We Offer Clients<br>
        Incorporation Services on a Global Scale<br>
        Free Consultation
    </p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, vai me ajudar bastante

Comment: @BrunoEusébio vc na verdade tem que entender o que foi feito, pare pra estudar um pouco sobre position e display isso sim vai te ajudar MUITO fica a dica

Comment: @BrunoEusébio se vc acha que o problema foi resolvido considere marcar a Resposta como Aceita ✓ assim ela não fica pendente no site como pegunta não respondia.